# Static Files Don't Work Django Elastic Beanstalk Amazon Linux 2

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Django project on EB on Amazon Linux 2. After running the collectstatic command, I can verify that there is a staticfiles folder. But when I go to the admin, the static files return 404

Here is my config file which doesn't work:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: backend.wsgi:application
  
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: backend.settings

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static/: staticfiles/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I removed the slash after the static like this and it worked:

```
option_settings:
  ...

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: staticfiles/
```

Comment: damn I've been struggling with this so bad

Comment: Is it possible to pass / for the path, so that the root serves a static site? like /: staticfiles/